# How can I increase row position using enumerate in python

Tags: python

I want to be able to find indices of certain characters in a matrix without importing numpy.

For example I have a matrix consists of . or O at random

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.']
['.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

I've come close to my solution using enumerate

```
for y, e in enumerate(content_matrix):
                for x, ee in enumerate(e):
                    if 'O' in ee:
                        print(x, y)
```

I want my output to be (0,7),(0,10),(0,11),(1,2),(2,7)....
and so on...

However, in the code I have above, it gives me

```
0 7
0 10
0 11
0 2
0 7
0 4
0 7
```

These sets of numbers. (Ignore the formatting for those numbers)

The x value(row value) is always 0 when it should be going up with the nth row.

What can I do to fix this problem?
Sorry for the awful wording in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you have something wrong with the declaration of you matrix?

I tred to store you matrix as:

```
content_matrix = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', 'O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

And your code provide me this output (that seems right to me):

```
7 0
10 0
11 0
2 1
7 2
4 3
7 3
```

Also, the output you provided does not seem consistent with the order in which x and y are printed.